# Почему и с чем зависимость в Maven конфликтует? (Spring Framework)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-data-jpa

Создал проект, в котором зависимости автоматически прописал сам Spring Framework, по мере написания потребовалось использование `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`, но при его подключении Spring отказывается запускать программу. Как решить?

```xml
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency> // после добавления этой зависимости перестает работать программа
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35845525/spring-boot-with-spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-dependency-wont-compile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавь в `application.properties` информацию по БД. А также драйвер JDBC для соответствующей БД.

Например:

```
spring.datasource.url=url
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
```